# Number of combinations that appear in two cells

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have a table that has numerous columns. I need to calculate the total number of units used when the combinations of Cells A and B Appear. For example

```
Column A             Column B         Column C
Original Lights      Upgraded Light   No. of Lights installed
A                    B                100
A                    C                50
C                    F                60
A                    B                50
D                    E                125
C                    F                55
```

I want in the new worksheet to return something similar to the following:

```
Column A             Column B         Column C
Original Lights      Upgraded Lights  No. of Lights installed
A                    B                150
A                    C                50
C                    F                115
D                    E                125
```

I hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Not sure in Excel 2013 but in Excel 2007 you can use the Consolidate wizard.

Create a column D that combines the value of column A and column B.  For example `=$A2 & "-" & $B2`.  This will be the "left label". Then you will need to copy column C to column E so that the data to be summed will be to the right of the "left label". That last step is required by the Consolation wizard.

Go to a new Sheet in Excel. Go to **Data**->**Consolidate** in the ribbon.  For **Function** choose "Sum".  For Reference, choose the range containing columns D and E.  Click the Add button to add the reference. Checkmark the "Top row" and "Left column" and press OK.

(update) If you want to split column D back into 2 columns, you can use (for example) `=LEFT($D2, FIND("-",$D2)-1)` and `=RIGHT($D2, LEN($D2) - FIND("-",$D2))`. Of course this assumes `-` doesn't appear in the values of column A or column B.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SUMIFS() in your new worksheet where, the formula in C2 - base on your example - would be `=SUMIFS(DataSheet!C:C,DataSheet!A:A,DataSheet!B:B,B2)`.

This would sum the values in the column C of your data sheet where the values in column A are equal to the value you place in "New Sheet"'s A2 and the values in column B are equal to the value you place in "New Sheet"'s B2.

Answer (score 0):

It's a typical use for a pivot table, add first and second columns as row labels and column 3 as values, and select sum as aggregation.